# Lazy load image tiles from grid container only visible on scrollviewer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm working on an offline map of sorts, loading them all at once consumes a ridiculous amount of memory. I've downloaded map images or tiles, with different zoom levels.

The Scrollviewer will act as the viewport and the grid container will be the canvas I will transform layout to achieve what I think is zooming. Can I get a result like lazyloading images that are visible in the viewport, Can anyone help me with this query? Thank you...

Comment: Welcome! It would be useful if you could show some of your current code, or attempts you have tried. Or an example of how the layout would work. It is tough to give a succinct answer from a more general question, with know how your infrastructure is setup.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.